# ICollection<T> is non-index based, but TakeWhile() exists

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I'm trying to replace usages of `T[]` or `List<T>` as function parameters and return values with more appropriate types such as `IEnumerable<T>`, `ICollection<T>` and `IList<T>`.

`ICollection<T>` from my understanding is preferrable to `IList<T>` where you are only needing basic/simple collection functionality (eg an enumerator and count functionality) as it provides this with the least restriction. From reading on here one of the main differentiators I thought was that `ICollection<T>` doesn't require that the underlying collection to be index based where `IList<T>` does?

In switching my `List<T>` references over I needed to replace a `List<T>.GetRange()` call and I was very surprised to find the `ICollection<T>.TakeWhile()` extension method which has an overload supporting selection based on index?! [(msdn link)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548775%28VS.96%29.aspx)

I'm confused why this method exists on ICollection where there is nothing index based on this interface? Have I misunderstood or how can this method actually work if the underlying collection is eg a Hashset or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method, like most of LINQ, is on `IEnumerable<T>`. Any features that just *pass the indexer to the consumer* (such as `TakeWhile`) only need to loop while incrementing a counter. Some APIs may be able to *optimize* using an indexer, and then it is up to them to decide whether to do that, or just use `IEnumerable<T>` and simply skip (etc) unwanted data.

For example:

```
int i = 0;
foreach(var item in source) {
    if(!predicate(i++, item)) break;
    yield return item;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Indexing can be done without collection's support of it

```
int i = -1;

foreach(var item in collection)
{
   i++;
   // item is at index i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`TakeWhile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534804.aspx) and other extension methods from [`System.Linq.Enumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx) class work on all the types implementing [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx). They all iterate over the collection (using `foreach` statement) and perform appropriate actions.

Here is the implementation of the `TakeWhile` method, with some simplifications:

```
private static IEnumerable<TSource> TakeWhile<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    foreach (TSource item in source)
    {
        if (!predicate(item))
        {
            break;
        }
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

As you see, it simply iterates over the collection, and evaluates the predicate. This is true for almost all other LINQ methods. The same will happen when you use any other collection, like `HashSet<T>`.